# PHP generated Javascript load via AJAX possible?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic, getscript

I need to load a dynamic created javascript with PHP. Is there any good solution to load javascript creating by PHP after some ajax requests finished?

Thx in regards, i am searching for 2h in stackoverflow.

if i call .ajax function where html/js respone, jquery kills the js ;/

Comment: you can put the response in eval()

Comment: works this only for js generated or if this result is with html too?

Comment: You can generate an entire HTML block with `<script>your JS here</script>` and append it to your document, you can create actual JS and use `eval()` like @shadow said or you can just rethink your approach and create a system that receives data from PHP and acts upon it.

Comment: @N.B. - thoughts I'd just mention that `<script>...</script>` blocks do not generally execute when you add them to the document.  I believe some libraries (Underscore?) do a bit of work to *simulate* this, by scanning for `<script>` tags and `eval(...)`ing them, but it doesn't happen automatically in any modern browser.

Comment: and what can i do then? a trigger event?

Comment: @Wykk: Are you *actually* doing code-generation in PHP?  That seems very bizarre.

Comment: yes i use it for googleapi for my articles

Comment: Do you want to receive a JSON response, and then make a separate request to get some JavaScript, or are you looking to *receive* JavaScript as a response, and execute it immediately?

Comment: I get it to work, i will make a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: $url,
    success: function(result)
      { 
         result // html

         jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'script',
         url: $url,
         success: function(result)
            { 
            //the result is js and is availble in browser if you return 
            //a function you can execute this now

            }
          });

      }
});
```

Hope someone find his answer here :) gl & hf & nice day

Comment: You should consider accepting your own answer. By that people can see the question is answered, and perhaps find the answer useful.